# The compiler will report warning when an instance is casted to a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I can't understand the code below. The complier report a warning. As I know, the generic type is erased. But I don't know why the code will generate a warning. Can anyone help me?

```
  public class Generic<T>{
            public void method(){
                    Object obj = new Object();
                    T t = (T)obj; // compile warning
            }
  }
```

After execute command "javac Generic.java -Xlint:unchecked", the information of warning is printed below

```
Generic.java:4: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        T t = (T) obj; // compile warning 
                  ^
  required: T
  found:    Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Generic
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm sorry.The code compliles, but the compiler report a warning.

Comment: Please add that information to your question.

Comment: It might depend on the compiler version. Have you tried <T extends Object> ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have edited the question,corrected mistakes in the question.

Comment: @AlexFitzpatrick The jdk is 1.8.0_20.After tried <T extends Object>,it still report a warning.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler issues a warning because it can be dangerous. In particular, it can lead to hard-to-track ClassCastExceptions. Let's see why.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code:

```
public class Generic<T> {
    public T method() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        T t = (T) obj; // warning
        return t;
    }
}
```

Because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the JVM can't actually check that `obj` is an instance of `T` at runtime; the cast it actually a no-op at runtime. And now consider this method, which takes a `Generic<T>` and adds its object to a list:

```
public static <T> void addToList(Generic<T> generic, List<T> list) {
    T t = generic.method();
    list.add(t);
}
```

And finally, let's use this `addToList` method:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
Generic<Integer> genericInt = new Generic<>();
addToList(genericInt, integers);
Integer theInt = integers.get(0); // ClassCastException!
```

Because of that type erasure, `addToList` couldn't do any type checking (the `T` in the method is just compiled to the most specific type that `T` could be, which in this case is `Object` because `T` is unbound). That means that it run successfully, but it put that `new Object()` ("cast" to `T`) in what should be a `List<Integer>`. It all works *until* you try to get the `Integer` out, at which point the compiler is forced to try to cast that `Object` to `Integer`. That last line compiles down to something like:

```
Integer theInt = (Integer) (integers.get(0));
```

And this throws a ClassCastException, since that first element was instantiated as `new Object()` (and thus isn't an `Integer`).

In this toy app, it's relatively straightforward to track down the actual problem. But consider a bigger application, where various things are putting elements into the `List`. Now you get a ClassCastException, and it can be tricky to find the buggy code that put the non-`Integer` object in the list.

So, that warning about unsafe casts is real -- the compiler is trying to tell you that the cast can't be checked at runtime, and thus is unsafe in that it could lead to hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: If you want to do a cast safely to a generic type, you can make your method take a `Class<T>` argument, and then call its [`cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) method.  Passing the class as an argument makes it available to the method at runtime, after type erasure has (effectively) replaced `T` with `Object`.  (Naturally, callers will have to pass the appropriate class object when calling the method.  The compile-time type checking will ensure that only the correct class *can* be passed.)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question raised by myself two years ago, but now I have already understand it.Firstly modify the define of Generic class like this

```
public class Generic<T> {
    public T method() {
        Object obj = new Object();
        T t = (T) obj;
        return t;
    }
}
```

Then if run the code below.

```
Generic<String> generic = new Generic<String>();
System.out.println("" + generic.method());
```

The crash will occur.The information of crash is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String